# AFNetworking : the current deployment target does not support automated _weak references

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

I'm using XCode 4.6.2 and also I'm new to iOS development. I'm trying to install the the AFNetworking library, but I get the following error when I'm trying to use it : `"The current deployment target does not support automated _weak references"` (when I try to display an image from an URL) in the files `AFHTTPClient` and `AFURLConnectionOperation`.

I don't have any weak properties in my little first project but only strong ones.

Any advice would be great!

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Weak references are only supported with iOS 5.0 and later. If your deployment target is set to 4.3 then you can't use `weak`. The error is probably coming from AFNetworking.

Drop support for iOS 4.3 if you can or don't use AFNetworking.

Comment: Indeed, the deployment target was set to by default? to 4.3. Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: @Reveclaire: Use __unsafe_unretained for __week properties. See this http://mobappdevelopment.wordpress.com/2013/01/10/deployment-target-does-not-support-automated-weak/

Answer (score 2):

To target the older OS, you can use unsafe_unretained instead of `weak` in your property declaration, and it should mostly work the same way. weak references nil themselves when their target goes away, but unsafe_unretained leaves open the possibility that the object you're linking to could turn into a dangling pointer when it is deallocated. The latter is the same behavior as if you had **used `assign` as a property** declaration in manual memory management.